# Run Illustrator script on multiple files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, illustrator-scripting

Is there a way to make an Illustrator script run over all files in a certain folder and perform operations on these?

I am using CS5 on mac.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Also, please indicate what version illustrator you are using.  You should look into Batch/Actions for Illustrator.  If you can explain what you are doing you could script a process in a shell script per ImageMagick or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve what you're after. You just have to decide what works best for your workflow/platform.

1. Have the script assign all *.ai files in a given directory to an array, then loop through.
2. If you're on OS X, set up an AppleScript droplet that will do the same as option 1 for any directory dropped on it.
3. Create a file prompt at the start of the script with multiple select enabled. This can be done with AppleScript, but I'm not sure about js.
4. Not exactly what you described but, the script could assign all open docs to an array. This way you wouldn't be limited by directory.

Comment: 5. make a script that acts upon and then closes an open file; create an action that runs the script; batch the action on a folder

Comment: @horatio sounds like a good alternate answer

Comment: Thanks - ended up using #1 which worked well! Only issue I stumbled on was that I had to replace 'file://' with '/' on Mac Mountain Lion for the folder path

Comment: Yeah, `file://` is a URL, you need the POSIX path for this purpose.

Comment: So how exactly do I modify an existing script to: Have the script assign all *.ai files in a given directory to an array, then loop through?